# Select same value count on each day

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table similar to this:

```
CREATE TABLE message(id int, type varchar(100), created timestamp);

insert into message (id, type, created) values (1, 'hello', '2014-04-16');
insert into message (id, type, created) values (2, 'hello', '2014-04-16');
insert into message (id, type, created) values (3, 'login', '2014-04-16');
insert into message (id, type, created) values (4, 'login', '2014-04-16');
insert into message (id, type, created) values (5, 'hello', '2014-04-17');
insert into message (id, type, created) values (6, 'hello', '2014-04-17');
insert into message (id, type, created) values (7, 'login', '2014-04-17');                     
insert into message (id, type, created) values (8, 'login', '2014-04-17');
insert into message (id, type, created) values (9, 'login', '2014-04-17');
insert into message (id, type, created) values (10, 'login', '2014-04-17');
```

I'd like to see the occurrences of the different types grouped by the `created` date.

If I run something like

```
select created, type, count(type)
from message
group by created, type
order by created
```

I get

```
created         type    count
April, 16 2014  hello   2
April, 16 2014  login   2
April, 17 2014  login   4
April, 17 2014  hello   2
```

What I'd like to have is

```
created         hello   login
April, 16 2014  2       2
April, 17 2014  2       4
```

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.3. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to count? Add one extra hello row to each date in your example!

Comment: Ok, so I added two extra login rows to April, 17.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
select created, count(case type when 'hello' then 1 else null end) AS hello,
count(case type when 'login' then 1 else null end) AS login
from message
group by created
order by created
```

**Update:**

From @SamiKuhmonen for Postgresql 9.4

```
select created, 
    count(*) filter (where type='hello') AS hello, 
    count(*) filter (where type='login') AS login 
from message 
group by created 
order by created;
```

Comment: Great job decoding the question!

Comment: @jarlh I'm struggling to see how it could be made for clear. Sorry.

Comment: @BalázsMáriaNémeth, no problem! (It's usually a good exercise trying to explain. Then your half way solvning the problem!)

Comment: You could also add for future reference the clearer version for Postgresql 9.4:  `select created, count(*) filter (where type='hello') AS hello, count(*) filter (where type='login') AS login from message group by created order by created;`